# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function, keep selecting slim version

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot

I'm trying to use ajax in spring boot project, and had problem with error code:
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

I've read all the previous answers, and found out that the problem was slim version.
however, all the solutions didn't work.

Here is my code:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

page.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
... ajax code
```

I found out that in the browser, somehow my project is still  slim version.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (7:156)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

[image]

I've spent whole day solving this problem, but couldn't figure out why my program is selecting 3.4.1.slim instead of 3.5.1 version.

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice, and one of them is the slim version.

Comment: If you're including jQuery from the CDN, you don't need the Maven dependency

Comment: @Barmar yeap it seems like, but I'm not sure what part of the code is loading it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just use this jquery and make call to ajax functions. You don't need to add maven dependency again to use jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I solved this by just adding that line right above another <script></> that actual javascript code is